# How to compare multiple rows from a table with conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following database structure.

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | first thread |
| 2 | second thread |

Thread table

| id | thread_id | participant_id | role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 301 | 1 | 101 | Super User |
| 302 | 1 | 102 | Admin |
| 303 | 1 | 103 | User |
| 304 | 2 | 101 | Super User |
| 305 | 2 | 102 | Admin |

Thread Participant Table

| id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 51 |
| 102 | 52 |
| 103 | 53 |

Participant Table

I  want to fetch unique threads where `participant id =101`  is present with `role Super user` but `participant id =103` should not be present.
How can I select such unique threads using sql.

Expected  Result :  thread id : 2

Note: I am using postgres

Edit: I found one solution but not sure is it optimal one

```
SELECT thread_id from  thread_participant tp where
tp.participant_id=101 and tp.role='Super User' GROUP BY tp.thread_id
Except
SELECT thread_id from  thread_participant tp1 where
tp1.participant_id=103  GROUP BY tp1.thread_id
```

Comment: Please add your expected results.

Comment: @Stu added  expected results